# Scala call single parameter method using space in anonymous class body

Tags: scala, anonymous-class, infix-notation

In scala, how can I call a single parameter method using space in the body of the anonymous class?

`add "Answer3"` below is not working

```scala
trait Question {
    def add(answer:String):Unit = {
        println("Received the answer=" + answer)
    }
}

object Test {
    val question:Question = new Question {
        this add "Answer1" // working

        add("Answer2")     // working
        
        add "Answer3"      // NOT working, why? -> error: ';' expected but string literal found.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to mix two different, and conflicting, convenience syntax options.

```
instance.method(argument)
```

... can be expressed as ...

```
instance method argument
```

... and, if the `method()` takes no argument then that can also be expressed with spaces, but the parser needs a little help.

```
instance method;
```

On a separate track, if the `instance` is `this` then that can be dropped.

```
method(argument)
```

But you can't drop the parentheses because the parser tries to interpret that as `instance method` and fails.

Comment: So `this add "Answer1"` works because it's `instance method argument` and `add "Answer3"` it's just `method argument` - won't work. I just wanted to sweeten the code even more with some syntactic sugar - but scala is sweet anyway :) -> Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Just found another nice explanation for this infix notation problem on the kotlin doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation: _Note that **infix functions always require both the receiver and the parameter to be specified**. When you're calling a method on the current receiver using the infix notation, use `this` explicitly. This is required to ensure unambiguous parsing._